# JBOSS JMS subscriber receiving messages with wrong selector

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq, jboss-eap-6

we use the below pseudo implementation for message synchronization between nodes in our Jboss clusters.

Pseudo-code is as follows-

```
void someMethod() {
Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup(topicName);

//create separate sessions for publisher and subscriber
this.publisher_session = this.connection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
this.publisher = publisher_session.createPublisher(topic);
this.subscriber_session = this.connection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
String selector = NAME_PROPERTY + "='" + getTestValue() + "'";
this.subscriber = subscriber_session.createSubscriber(topic,selector,true);

subscriber.setMessageListener(this);    
connection.setExceptionListener(this);
this.connection.start();
}

protected void publish(Message message)
{
    try
    {
      synchronized (publisher_session)
      {
        ObjectMessage objMessage =
          getSession().createObjectMessage(message);
        objMessage.setStringProperty(NAME_PROPERTY, getTestValue());
        getPublisher().publish(objMessage);
      }
    }
    catch (JMSException e)
    {
      logger.error("Failed to publish message: " + message + " for "
                   + getTestValue(), e);
    }
}


 public void onMessage(Message message)
  {
    // Validate type
    if (!(message instanceof ObjectMessage))
    {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException
        ("message not instanceof ObjectMessage: " + message.getClass());
    }

    ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;

    try
    {
      // Validate selector
      if (!objectMessage.getStringProperty
          (NAME_PROPERTY).equals(getTestValue()))
      {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
          ("Selector mechanism failed: received message regarding "
           + objectMessage.getStringProperty(NAME_PROPERTY));    <========== THIS EXCEPTION GETS THROWN
      }
        // Further code 
    }
    catch (JMSException ex)
    {
      logger.error("Problem getting message for " + getTestValue(), ex);
    }
  }
```

Expectation here is that since selector matches the value of `objMessage.setStringProperty(NAME_PROPERTY, getTestValue())`, respective messages will arrive for subscriber and then the validation will pass.

But this is not happening.

The onMessage() method keeps throwing exception for some time and after restart, starts behaving fine, till it misbehaves once again. Currently running in JBOSS EAP 6.0.1

Comment: What exception is `onMessage()` throwing? Have you reproduced this with a later version of JBoss EAP? Version 6.0.1 is quite old at this point.

Comment: Also, there are a bunch of reasons *not* to use `ObjectMessage`. Is there a specific reason why you're using it?